# PHP does not update file opened one time in page?

Tags: php, fread

(Sorry my bad english)
I tryed to create a script PHP that show the inicial content of the file, update it and show content updated.
I need this operations in this order.
I already tryed fflush() before the fclose() but it does not worked.

My expected result:
-When opened page
first:
second: 0
-When refresh page
first: 0
second: **0 0**
-When refresh page again
first: 0 0
second: **0 0 0**
-And so on.

My result is:
-When opened page
first:
second: 0
-When refresh page
first: 0
second: **0**
-When refresh page again
first: 0 0
second: **0 0**
-And so on.

Code:

```
$v = "";
echo file_exists("teste");

if (file_exists("teste")) {
  if (filesize("teste") != 0) {
    $f = fopen("teste", 'r');
    $v = fread($f, filesize("teste"));
    fclose($f);
    echo "first:" . $v;
  }
}

$f = fopen("teste", 'w');
fwrite($f, $v);
fwrite($f, "0 ");
fclose($f);

$f = fopen("teste", 'r');
$v = fread($f, filesize("teste"));
fclose($f);
echo "<br />";
echo "second:". $v;
?>
```

why? is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`, it might reduce some of the errors tyou have there.

Answer (score 0):

`'w'` recreates the file anew each time. Use `'r+'` and seek to the end, or `'a'`.